# Generate a PDF in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to generate a PDF in **Angular2**, it downloads the PDF and it downloads a blank page without any content, when I change it from **addHTML** to **fromHTML** PDF has the content when I open it in browser but when I open it using adobe it shows error 'contact the person who generated this PDF'. Can you help me with this?

```
generatePDF() {  
        let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');  
        let source = document.getElementById("printOffers1");  
        doc.addHTML(source, () => {  
        });  
        doc.save('fileName.pdf');  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to generate PDF:

```
generatePDF() {  

                let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

                let options = {
                    background : "#ffff",
                    pagesplit: true
                };

                let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                let constant = document.getElementById("printOffers1");

                doc.addHTML(constant,0,0,options,()=>{
                      doc.save("test.pdf");
                    });

            }
```

Comment: Vignesh, Thank you for the response. I tried working with the solution you shared, it is not downloading the PDF. I tried the other way using html2canvas, it downloads the PDF as 'Image' but I need to display it as text for my angular2 project.

Comment: @Jay for angular2 controls the pdf has not implemented yet. So Using html2canvas it taking screen shot of the current page and downloads in .pdf format.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Vignesh